# Combine Two LIsts in Unique Way in Python

Tags: python, list

I am working on Project Euler problem 5 and am using the following:

```
def findLCM(k):
start=time.time()
primes=[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23]
factors=[]
for factor in range(2,k):
    if factor in primes:
        factors.append(factor)
    else:
        factorization=[]
        while factor!=1:
            for prime in primes:
                lastFactor=prime
                if factor%prime==0:
                    factor/=prime
                    factorization.append(lastFactor)
                    break
        tmpFactors=[]
        for tmpFactor in factorization:
            if tmpFactor not in factors:
                factors.append(tmpFactor)
            else:
                tmpFactors.append(tmpFactor)
                factors.remove(tmpFactor)
        for tmpFactor in tmpFactors:
            factors.append(tmpFactor)
        print factors
product=1
for factor in factors:
    product*=factor
factors.sort()
end=time.time()
fnTime=end-start
return product, fnTime, factors
```

Is there a Python function with which I can combine factorization and factors like this function does? For example, if `factors=[2, 3, 5]` and `factorization=[2, 2, 3]`, the combined list should be `[2, 2, 3, 5]`.

Comment: Project Euler problem 5:

2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder. What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

Comment: Also, if you know what the mathematical lingo for such a union of two sets of numbers is, please let me know.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The terminology is "union of [multisets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset)".

It is implemented in Python using *[collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#counter-objects)*:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> combined = Counter([2, 3, 5]) | Counter([2, 2, 3])
>>> list(combined.elements())
[2, 2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Wow.  I had no idea that Counter supported the `|` operator (where is that even documented?).  Brilliant answer.  (+1 from me).